# Parsing JSON array nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, httprequest

so I'm learning NodeJS and javascript in general, and playing around with it and I have some problems parsing a JSON. I receive the following from the "user":

```
{
  "sync_contact_list": [
    {
      "name": "c",
      "number": "789",
      "email": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "number": "123",
      "email": "a@a.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "a",
      "number": "416",
      "email": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is how can i properly parse this to get the individual bits:

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "number": "416",
  "email": ""
}
```

I've been trying to do it by doing var jsonObject = JSON.parse(req.body); ,but I keep getting parsing errors, no matter how I vary the JSON that I do receive (individual components, all of it, etc).

Could anyone one point out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
So i use express to deal with the different paths. So i have app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
//var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  //app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());  
});

// Routes

//app.post('/', routes.syncServiceIndex);

app.post('/syncService', routes.synchServicePost);
app.get('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/sync', routes.synchServiceSync);
app.post('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/push', routes.synchServicePush);
app.del('/syncService/:syncServiceUser', routes.synchServiceDel);

app.post('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/push', routes.synchServiceContactsPush);
app.get('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/sync', routes.synchServiceContactsSync);

app.post('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/', routes.synchServiceContactsPost);
app.get('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/:contactId', routes.synchServiceContactsGet);
app.put('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/:contactId', routes.synchServiceContactsPut);
app.del('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/:contactId', routes.synchServiceContactsDel);


app.listen(3000);


console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

And then I have index.js, where I basically have the following for each route.

```
exports.synchServicePost = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServicePost');
    console.log("BODY:"+JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(req.body);


    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
}
```

The request is made with a line free JSON:

```
curl -i -d "{'sync_contact_list':[{'name':'c','number':'789','email':''},{'name':'b','number':'123','email':'a@a.com'},{'name':'a','number':'416','email':''}]}"  http://localhost:3000/syncService
```

EDIT: I realized I should probably change the Content Type to application/json. in this case, for JSON.stringify I get the following:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/alex/peekcode/quipmail/synch/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:71:15)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:61:17)
at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
at Socket.ondata (http.js:1029:22)
at Socket._onReadable (net.js:677:27)
at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
```

Comment: What does the parsing error say? You do have to parse the complete response and then just access result.sync_contact_list[0] for the first result.

Comment: Try it with a linebreak-/spacefree json. Does that work?

Comment: @AronWoost may be right. Is the data from the user **exactly** in the format you provided? Or you just formatted it for the StackOverflow? I assumed you are showing us only the structure of the data you want to receive, but we should be given the exact `req.body` value along with its type (try invoking `typeof req.body` and give us the result).

Comment: @Tadeck req.body= {"{'sync_contact_list':":{"{'name':'c','number':'789','email':''},{'name':'b','number':'123','email':'a@a.com'},{'name':'a','number':'416','email':''}]":""}}

Comment: @user652360: You're using invalid JSON.

Comment: ...you need double quotes around property names and strings. `'{"sync_contact_list":[{"name":"c","number":"789","email":""},{"name":"b","number":"123","email":"a@a.com"},{"name":"a","number":"416","email":""}]}'`

Comment: @user652360: From what we can see (looking at your comment) your `req.body`: 1) is not a string, 2) is invalid. But probably we are seeing something else than you have written (due to StackOverflow displaying it differently). This is why I asked you also about the result of `typeof req.body` - which will tell us something more on what `req.body` really is.

Comment: @RightSaidFred is right. I can't believe i didn't notice that. I was using an online JSON viewer to detect any msising commas, and for some reason it accept my JSON strings with the " and ' inversed and i paid no further notice to it.

However, when I try to parse it, i get "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it is already parsed? I do not know (I did not see your whole code).

If it is (or you will parse it the way you need), then specific "bits" will be available like that (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs9Qx/) for a proof):

```
for (var i=0; i<jsonObject['sync_contact_list'].length; i++){
    // here jsonObject['sync_contact_list'][i] is your current "bit"
}
```

Within the loop, between iterations, `jsonObject['sync_contact_list'][i]` changes between the "bits", because `i` changes and points to the first element, then to the second, and so on, until the last element.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out my JSON was badly formatted. Bad habit I got from working on a Java project. Once that part was fixed, my request was getting parsed by default, which caused some other headache until I found out about node-inspector.

As a result, I'm selecting Tadeck as having the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(count in sync_contact_list) {
           console.log('individual json objects list', JSON.stringify(sync_contact_list[count]));
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.